# Trouble converting a class to function in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to rewrite this code from class to a function. I've never used classes but I got this test code for a calendar app while learning react native but I seem to get stuck somewhere when I'm trying to replace componentDidUpdate to useEffect.

**This is the old code:**

```
export default class DaysInMonth extends React.PureComponent{

state = {
    lastCalendarDayIndex: 0, 
    currentCalendarDayIndex: 0,
}

changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex = (index) => {
    this.setState({
        currentCalendarDayIndex: index
    })
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if(this.state.currentCalendarDayIndex !== prevState.currentCalendarDayIndex){
        this.setState({
            lastCalendarDayIndex: prevState.currentCalendarDayIndex
        })
    }
}

render(){
    return(
        <>
            {
                this.props.row_days_array.map((rowData, index) => (
                    <CalendarRow 
                        key = {'calendar row ' + index}
                        rowData = {rowData}

                        lastCalendarDayIndex = {this.state.lastCalendarDayIndex}
                        changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex = {this.changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex}
                        month_index = {this.props.month_index}
                        current_month_index = {this.props.current_month_index}
                        chooseDifferentMonth = {this.props.chooseDifferentMonth}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

}

**And this is the new code** everything works except for some functions which has to do with the useEffect, I don't understand what properties I should add to get the same functionality as before. Thanks

```
export default function DaysInMonth({row_days_array, month_index, current_month_index, chooseDifferentMonth}) {
 const [lastCalendarDayIndex, setLastCalendarDayIndex] = useState(0)
 const [currentCalendarDayIndex, setCurrentCalendarDayIndex] = useState(0)

 const changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex = (index) => {
    setCurrentCalendarDayIndex(index)
}

useEffect(() => {
    if(currentCalendarDayIndex !== currentCalendarDayIndex){
        setLastCalendarDayIndex(currentCalendarDayIndex)
    }

  },[]);

  return (
    <>
        {row_days_array.map((rowData, index) => (
            <CalendarRow 
                key = {'calendar row ' + index}
                rowData = {rowData}

                lastCalendarDayIndex = {lastCalendarDayIndex}
                changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex = {changeCurrentCalendarDayIndex}

                month_index = {month_index}
                current_month_index = {current_month_index}
                chooseDifferentMonth = {chooseDifferentMonth}
            />
        ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What this does:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(currentCalendarDayIndex !== currentCalendarDayIndex){
        setLastCalendarDayIndex(currentCalendarDayIndex)
    }
},[]);
```

It runs the code inside useEffect every time the array changes. Because it's an empty array it will just run once (once the component mounts, this is basically the old `ComponentDidMount`), to mimic the behaviour of `ComponentDidUpdate` you need to keep track of the `props` so it should be a matter of passing them into the array (so React can track when it changes):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(currentCalendarDayIndex !== currentCalendarDayIndex){
        setLastCalendarDayIndex(currentCalendarDayIndex)
    }
},[props]);
```

It's probably easier to change the destructuring you have in the component definition `{row_days_array, month_index, current_month_index, chooseDifferentMonth}` to `props` and then destructure a bit bellow, so you can use the whole object in you `useEffect` array

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work but I see the logic it makes sense. Think I might have missed something else in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback in setState to access previous state, and pass currentCalendarDayIndex in useEffect dependency to update lastedCalendarState every currentCalendar changes. Hope this can help!

```
useEffect(() => {
   setLastCalendarDayIndex((prevCalendarDayIndex) => 
       prevCalendarDayIndex !== currentCalendarDayIndex 
       ? currentCalendarDayIndex 
       : prevCalendarDayIndex)
}, [currentCalendarDayIndex])
```